# Evaluate iot algorithms with cooja simulator

Tags: simulation, iot, omnet++, contiki, cooja

I wrote an algorithm for authentication in iot home network.
Now i want to evaluate it with related works.(Without using real testbed)
Can I use Cooja simulator to do it?
Or Its better to use omnet++?

Comment: At the moment this post is not a good fit for StackOverflow. Please look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and reformulate this query to a specific question.

Comment: You definitely need to extend your question with additional information (set-up, protocol stack, etc.) to allow any kind of answer to your question!